# How to loop an array with loop time double the array length/size

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, loops, settimeout

how can I loop through an array of character with fixed element in it ( in my case is 4 items in the array) n time (for n can be changed)? I'm trying to make a spinner using setTimeout and \r, and the initial code is:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  process.stdout.write('\r|   ');
}, 100);

setTimeout(() => {
  process.stdout.write('\r/   ');
}, 300);

setTimeout(() => {
  process.stdout.write('\r-   ');
}, 500);

setTimeout(() => {
  // Need to escape the backslash since it's a special character.
  process.stdout.write('\r\\   '); 
}, 700);
```

But I want to increase the running time for the spinner, the simpler approach is copying and pasting those line again and increasing the delay time parameter. However, I'm trying to make it shorter by using the loop and come up with this (just testing for the output from array, not yet implementing the setTimeout in the loop):

```
const char = ['|', '/', '-', '\\'];
// want to repeat the char 2 times for longer run
const nRun = char.length * 2;
for (let i = 0; i < nRun; i++){
  console.log(char[i]);
}
```

But the array.length is only 4, if I do this, it would output undefined for the 5th->8th time it run through the loop. Is it possible for these codes to be put into a loop?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: *simple approach -.-! sorry

Comment: You can fix your typo using [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68917585/edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the remainder operator (`%`) in order to loop in your array like it's a ring:

```
const char = ['|', '/', '-', '\\'];
// want to repeat the char 2 times for longer run
const nRun = char.length * 2;
for (let i = 0; i < nRun; i++){
  console.log(char[i % 4]); // <= change here
}
```

> The remainder operator (%) returns the remainder left over when one operand is divided by a second operand.

You can learn more about this operator here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder

Comment: thank youu. I never thought that % can be used this way inside the loop to make it runs again.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use a string since a string is an iterable.

```js
const char = '|/-\\';
// want to repeat the char 2 times for longer run
const nRun = char.length * 2;
for (let i = 0; i < nRun; i++){
  console.log(char[i%4]);
}
```

You can also use .forEach() on an array converted from the string:

```js
    const char = '|/-\\';
    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) Array.from(char).forEach((c,j) => setTimeout(()=>console.log(c),i*1000+j*250));
```

Comment: thank you a lot for your help and an extra solution using .forEach() too.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers used  %4

Alternatively you can double the array:

`char = char.concat(char)`

```js
let char = ['|', '/', '-', '\\'];
// want to repeat the char 2 times for longer run
const nRun = char.length * 2;
char = char.concat(char)
for (let i = 0; i < nRun; i++){
  console.log(char[i]);
}
```